# What to do when a poster admits they are using a second account

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, sock-puppets

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13424481/656243), the user admits to be using a newly create account because

> SO has somehow locked me out of my account and I apparently can't post
>   images with this new one

What's the best channel for notifying the right people?

Comment: The user probably got question banned.

Comment: @Mysticial Indeed, it's possible that the vagueness of being 'somehow locked out' could be intentional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag the post and leave a note for the moderators.

In general, though, I don't think this is a big problem. Using a new account to get around an actual timed suspension aside...

Having multiple accounts isn't always a bad thing. Sure, using one to get around a question block on another isn't exactly encouraged, but if the user has learned from their mistakes... there's no need to penalize them. And if they haven't, they'll get question-blocked again in due time.

These things tend to have a way of working themselves out.

Comment: Do tools exist to compare the IP of the poster against other accounts/posts that have used the same IP (with the end goal of determining who the user is, and what the reason was for being banned?)

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Yes, we can look up if a user has other accounts.

Comment: Say. When is having multiple accounts not a bad thing? I'm curious. =)

Comment: @J.Steen Some folks like to keep a separate account for "simpler" questions. There's nothing wrong with it so long as one account doesn't vote for posts made from the other, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't dream of it.

Answer (score 1):

Flag the post for moderator attention. They will check that and take appropiate actions if necesarry.